# How to extend AppCompatActivity for an activity which extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>?

Tags: java, android

I updated the Android Studio from 3.XX to 4.0. Eventually, some activity names declared in AndroidManifest.xml went underlined asking for below actions.

```
This class should provide a default constructor.
Class must extend android.app.Activity
```

I overcome these errors of few activities by declaring an empty constructor and by extending [AppCompatActivity]. 
But for other few activities which extends ArrayList [ like the one below ], I can't extend [AppCompatActivity].

```
public class Apex extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

}
```

Multiple inheritance in Java is not allowed but only by interface. How to fix this?

Comment: could you share some code or a screenshot, I doubt that you would get this error for an ArrayAdapter. And only activities should be added to the AndroidManifest.

Comment: I solved the issue with the program. Posted an answer for reference by users & friends in SO. Thank you, @Wirling! – MdBasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities are activities and Array Adapters are array adapters for list views or any other type of list. When you extend a class from another that means that both classes have the same purpose/usage which is not the case for an activity and array adapter.

If you define an activity in the manifest then the activity can only extend any other platform activity (Activity, AppCompatActivity, etc..), then you must create another class that extends from ArrayAdapter and use it in your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

In common, you need to use composition rather than inheritance.

So you don't need to inherit of ArrayAdapter, just create an instance of ArrayAdapter as a field of the Activity.

For example https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exter extends AppCompatActivity{

            public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
            private Apx adapter; /// Instance for Adapter

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
              
            }
            
    //// Here coded the Adapter class       
            
    public class Apx extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> 
    {
     
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ApList;
        Activity activity;
       
        public Apx(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ApList) 
        {
            super(activity, R.layout.simple, ApList);
            this.activity = activity;
            this.ApList= ApList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            return convertView;
        }

    }
        
}
```

Hope it is clear!